# Use vue-sweetalert2 from axios plugin in Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios, nuxt.js, vue-sweetalert2

I'm building an interceptor to handle errors from `@nuxtjs/axios` in my `Nuxt` app, but when I try to call `vue-sweetalert2` from the axios plugin to show the error messages it throws me: `$swal is not a function`.

I have an alerts plugin and imported it to plugins section in `nuxt.config`, I use it to import Sweetalert globally and to handle a global loader, it works in other moments, but not when trying to call it from axios:

```
//plugins/alerts.js

import Vue from 'vue'


// I remove the following two lines when I import swal directly as a module in nuxt.config.js

import VueSweetalert2 from 'vue-sweetalert2';
Vue.use(VueSweetalert2);

Vue.mixin({
    methods: {
        alertLoading(action, message = "") {
            if (action === "show") {
                this.$swal.fire({
                    title: message,
                    imageUrl: "/img/Loader.gif",
                    allowOutsideClick: false,
                    showConfirmButton: false,
                    showCancelButton: false
                });
            } else {
                this.$swal.close()
            }
        },
        alertError(title, msg = undefined) {
            this.$swal(title, msg, 'error')
        }
    }
})
```

My `axios.js` plugin:

```
/* I've trid importing it directly and doesn't work
import Vue from 'vue'

import VueSweetalert2 from 'vue-sweetalert2';
Vue.use(VueSweetalert2);*/

export default async ({ app, $axios }, inject) => {
    $axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    $axios.defaults.mode = "no-cors"

    $axios.onError(error => {
        cont response = error.response
        if (response && response.data && response.data.msg) {
            this.$swal("Error", response.data.msg, "error") // TypeError: Cannot read property '$swal' of undefined
            // app.$swal("Error", response.data.msg, "error") //app.$swal is not a function
        }
    })
}
```

I've tried adding this code also to my plugin with no success:

```
const swal = require('vue-sweetalert2')
swal({
    title: 'Error', 
    text: 'Error', 
    confirmButtonColor: "#895CF2",
    confirmButtonText: 'Close',
    type: 'error'
})
```

How do I call $swal from this axios instance? Is there a way to access Nuxt's `this` instance?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This error appears when the `vue-sweetalert2` is not properly configured as a Nuxt module. Your Nuxt config should contain the following entry in the `modules` array:

*nuxt.config.js:*

```js
module.exports = {
  modules: [
    'vue-sweetalert2/nuxt',
  ]
}
```

Also, you don't need to explicitly install the plugin:

*plugins/axios.js:*

```js
// XXX: No need to install `vue-sweetalert2` here
// import Vue from 'vue'
// import VueSweetalert2 from 'vue-sweetalert2';
// Vue.use(VueSweetalert2);

export default async ({ app }) => {
  app.$swal('hello world')
}
```

[GitHub demo](https://github.com/tony19-sandbox/vue-sweetalert2-nuxt-demo)

Comment: Please provide a link to your code to reproduce the problem

Comment: I think my problem is related to SSR, I print `app.$swal` and gives me undefined, but other plugins like `app.$auth` work.